# Purity and six operations?

Tags: etale-cohomology, flag-varieties, six-operations, constructible-sheaves

The six operations $f_!,f^!,f_*,f^*,\otimes,\mathcal Hom$ have the property that they preserve estimates on weights in one direction.

For $f_!,f^!,f_*,f^*$ I can see, that they don't preserve purity general. One can also give sufficient criteria for them to preserve purity, by ensuring them to be "equivalent" to their dual (smooth pullback, proper pushforward...).

What about the other operations $\otimes,\mathcal Hom$? What is an example of two pure sheaves, such that say $\cal F \otimes \cal G$ is not pure anymore?

Are there condtions that force $\otimes,\mathcal Hom$ to preserve purity? (By making them equivalent to their dual?)

I am most interested in the following situation:

Let $IC_x$ and $IC_y$ be two Bruhat constructible $IC$-sheaves on a partial flag variety. Then it is well known, that the space $Ext^{\bullet}(IC_x,IC_y)$ is pure. Does the sheaf version of this statement hold as well? Is the sheaf ${\cal Hom}(IC_x,IC_y)$ pure?

Comment: Re your question of two pure sheaves whose tensor product is not pure:  take an IC complex which is not pointwise pure (a simple example is provided by the $H^1$ of a degenerating family of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$). Then tensor it with the skyscraper at a point where the IC is not pointwise pure.

Comment: Another (easier) example: take two smooth subvarieties which intersect in something reducible, then the tensor product of the constant sheaves on these two subvarieties will yield the constant sheaf on a reducible subvariety, which is not pure.

Comment: One more comment and I'll quit :) The problem with tensor product is that there are really two tensor products: given $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ on $X$, form $\mathcal{F} \boxtimes \mathcal{G}$ on $X \times X$. Then the two tensor products correspond to $*$ and $!$ restriction to the diagonal. (This is explained well in Ginzburg if I recall correctly.)

Comment: Thanks for these examples! Can you be more precise about what "in Ginzburg" refers to:)

Comment: I was also wondering, if there are conditons on input sheaves, which ensure that their $!$ and $*$ tensor product coincide (up to shift and twist).

Comment: "In Ginzburg": http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9802004v3.pdf around equation (24).

Comment: I guess you want the diagonal inclusion $X \hookrightarrow X \times X$ to be "non-characteristic" (terminology as in Kashiwara-Schapira) for the two definitions of tensor product to agree up to a shift/twist.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Can you also comment on the flag variety question?

Comment: I don't think it will be true: take a rank two flag variety. Then the Schubert varieties corresponding to $st$ and $ts$ intersect in the union of $s$ and $t$ which is reducible. Hence my second (easier) example applies.

Comment: Very interesting! This makes the purity of the $Ext$-algebra even more miraculous. Thanks a lot for your observations, they clarified things for me. If I could I would accept your comments as an answer.

Comment: Just a minor addition to Geordie's comments: note that $M\otimes N = \Delta^*(M\boxtimes N)$ and $\mathcal{H}om(M,N) = \Delta^!(\mathbb{D}M\boxtimes N)$.